# Array of Structs as Function Argument

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I have an array of structs, and I just want to pass it to the function in order to sort it. What am I doing wrong, as far as passing the array of structs into the function? What errors are there in the prototype, call, and definition?

**NOTE** -  I realize I have not initialized the array of structs. In my actual code, the array has data from a text file in it. That is not relevant to the question I am asking. So please do not comment about not having anything in the array.

Here is a little sample of code that I can't get to work:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct checkType
{
    char date[12];
    char checkNum[8];
    float amount;
};

void bubbleSort(checkType, const int);

int main()
{
    const int NUM = 5;
    checkType checkArray[NUM];

    bubbleSort(checkArray, NUM);

    return 0;
}

void bubbleSort(checkType array[], const int SIZE)
{
    bool swap;
    checkType temp;

    do
    {
        swap = false;

        for (int count = 0; count < (SIZE - 1); count++)
        {
            if (strcmp(array[count].date, array[count + 1].date) > 0)
            {
                temp = array[count];
                array[count] = array[count + 1];
                array[count + 1] = temp;
                swap = true;
            }
        }
    } while (swap);

}
```

This code produces this error:

> error C2664: 'void bubbleSort(checkType,const int)' : cannot convert
>   argument 1 from 'checkType [5]' to 'checkType'

So then I tried to change the function call from `bubbleSort(checkArray, NUM);` to `bubbleSort(checkArray[NUM], NUM);`

This code produces these errors:

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl
>   bubbleSort(struct checkType,int)" (?bubbleSort@@YAXUcheckType@@H@Z)
>   referenced in function _main
>
> error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Could someone please explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Just do `MY_STRUCT_TYPE **array`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Forward declaration:

```
void bubbleSort(checkType, const int);
```

Definition:

```
void bubbleSort(checkType array[], const int SIZE)
```

Those are not the same.  The forward declaration should be:

```
void bubbleSort(checkType[], const int);
```